# Python regular expression expansion

Tags: python, regex

I am really bad with regular expressions, and stuck up to generate all the possible combinations for a regular expression.

When the regular expression is `abc-defghi00[1-24,2]-[1-20,23].walmart.com`, it should generate all its possible combinations.

The text before the braces can be anything and the pattern inside the braces is optional.

Need all the python experts to help me with the code.

Sample output
Here is the expected output:

```
abc-defghi001-1.walmart.com
.........
abc-defghi001-20.walmart.com
abc-defghi001-23.walmart.com
..............
abc-defghi002-1.walmart.com
Repeat this from 1-24 and 2.
```

Regex tried

```
([a-z]+)(-)([a-z]+)(\[)(\d)(-)(\d+)(,?)(\d?)(\])(-)(\[)(\d)(-)(\d+)(,?)(\d?)(\])(.*)
```

Comment: Even a regex expert :)

Comment: Here is the expected output:                                         
abc-defghi001-1.walmart.com
.........
abc-defghi001-20.walmart.com
abc-defghi001-23.walmart.com
..............
abc-defghi002-1.walmart.com
Repeat this from 1-24 and 2.

Comment: Nice, What did you tried?

Comment: was trying to create a regex and than use group function in recursion

Comment: post the regex tried in your question.

Comment: Posted it in the question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Needed you assistance?

Comment: What do you mean by 1 to 24 and 2?!

Comment: 2 is just an example, maybe something like 27, it will generate all the combinations from 1 to 24 and than for 27 as well.

Comment: Is my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: nope...I want to generate all the possible patterns for this expression.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we would like to match against `abc-defghi001-1.walmart.com`. Now, if we write the following regex, it does the job.

```
s = 'abc-defghi001-1.walmart.com'
re.match ('.*[1-24]-[1-20|23]\.walmart\.com',s)
```

and the output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x029462C0>
```

So, its found. If you want to match to 27 in the first bracket, you simply replace it by `[1-24|27]`, or if you want to match to 0 to 29, you simply replace it by `[1-29]`. And ofcourse, you know that you have to write `import re`, before all the above commands.

Edit1: As far as I understand, you want to generate all instances of a regular expression and store them in a list. 
Use the `exrex` python library to do so. You can find further information about it [here](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex). Then, you have to limit the regex you use.

Comment: These values are dynamic not static

Comment: What do you mean? It matches your sample expected outputs. If you clearly explain what you are looking for I may be able to help you.

Comment: If a user enters a pattern like this, it should generate a list
abc-defghi001-1.walmart.com
.........
abc-defghi001-20.walmart.com
abc-defghi001-23.walmart.com
..............
abc-defghi002-1.walmart.com
Repeat this from 1-24 and 2.

Comment: Its basically regex expansion

Comment: exrex is not working, it does not understand these expressions, it needs a proper regex as input.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = 'abc-defghi001-1.walmart.com'
obj=re.match(r'^\w{3}-\w{6}00(1|2)-([1-20]|23)\.walmart\.com$',s)
print(obj.group())
```

The above regex will match the template you're looking for I hope!